# JavaScript/jQuery .replace math inquiry

Tags: javascript, jquery, math

```
$(function() {
    var links = $(".notranslate").map(function() {
        var gg = this.href
        gg.replace(/\D/g,'');
    }).get();
    console.log(links);
});
```

I'm curious on how I would make this just return the numbers out of the part that it logged.

```
Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace'
```

Comment: Show example of the links.

Comment: And it also should be `return gg.replace(/\D/g, '');`.

Comment: And just a [workable fiddle version](http://jsfiddle.net/vooh0y33/).

Comment: ["http://www.roblox.com/User.aspx", "http://www.roblox.com/User.aspx?ID=71363535", "http://www.roblox.com/User.aspx?ID=71699678", "http://www.roblox.com/User.aspx?ID=71699678", "http://www.roblox.com/User.aspx?ID=71699660", "http://www.roblox.com/User.aspx?ID=71699660", "http://www.roblox.com/User.aspx?ID=71699642", "http://www.roblox.com/User.aspx?ID=71699642", "http://www.roblox.com/User.aspx?ID=71699618", "http://www.roblox.com/User.aspx?ID=71699618", "http://www.roblox.com/User.aspx?ID=4681365", "http://www.roblox.com/User.aspx?ID=4681365"]

Comment: Those are the links, it still errors @Regent

Comment: Here's a fiddle with a few of your links added. Still works. http://jsfiddle.net/vooh0y33/1/ Voting to close as non-reproducible

Comment: Apparently you have some elements with the `.notranslate` class that do not have a `href`. Maybe try `$("[href].notranslate")`